# c++ template: intiantiating a variable out of a particular integer (as type)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, integer

I've obviously misunderstood the code. Thanks for pointing out the error.

--original post--

I know for a while that integers can be used as types in c++ template programming. What surprises me is that when an integer such as 2 and 3 is used as a type, one can actually instantiate a variable out of the type, as shown in the example below extracted from gcc 4.8.1 `random.h`.

It seems to me that one can declare a variable

```
2 x; //not actual c++ code
```

and x will be an integer variable initialized to the value of `2`.

Code for deterniming whether a number is a power of 2:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename _Tp> inline bool
  _Power_of_2(_Tp __x)  {
         return ((__x - 1) & __x) == 0;
  };

int main() {
  std::cout << _Power_of_2(2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << _Power_of_2(3) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

Can someone please explain what's going on here in terms of types and domains?

Are there any similar features in other programming languages that can do the same, i.e. using a concrete value as a type?

Also, is this feature available for other types, such as `struct`, `string` or `float`?

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you see the use of an integer as a type in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `2` is not used as a type, but as a function parameter. From that, the template parameter `_tP` is automatically deduced as `int`. So the lines inside `main` would be equivalent to:

```
std::cout << _Power_of_2<int>(2) << std::endl;
std::cout << _Power_of_2<int>(3) << std::endl;
```